# nginx cache not working

Tags: caching, nginx

I'm trying to set up caching in nginx (which is front ended to tomcat) but the cache is always empty. The contents of nginx.conf is below

```html
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    proxy_buffering                 on;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

  

    proxy_cache_path /path/to/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g
                 inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_cache my_cache;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

The directory `/path/to/cache` has only one directory called `temp` that gets created. Making repeated requests on nginx doesn't create any cache as `/path/to/cache` is empty. Any idea what is it that I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Does nginx has access to your cache folder? `chown -R nginx "/path/to/cache"` and restart nginx after that

Comment: Yes it does. I double checked it with `chown -R nginx:nginx "/path/to/cache" ` and restarted, no dice.

Comment: Do a `curl -v <your url>` and post the log of the same

Comment: make sure that your call is going through the "location / " location block. eg: remove the proxy_pass in that block and test it it should return 404.    

PS:do you have any other conf file other than this in the include directories?

Comment: Maybe your requests are ignored by `Cache-Control` header? Have you tried adding `proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;` into your location block? Also adding `add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;` and checking in the browser (if possible) if cache was `HIT` or `MISS` might help with debug.